# How to show horizontal line in iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating a pdf and need to put a horizontal line in the page. Can anyone tell how to do that?

I have a xml file which has my html tag(`<table>....</table>`). And the whole content of `xml` file is parsed to a `string` which is used to create the `pdf`. Now some tags are not supported. One of them is `<hr>`.  So is there any other tag which I can use in the `xml` file so that this will draw  a 
`line` when the pdf is created using xml data.

Below is an example of xml xontent

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <span>
           This is working properly.
       </span>
     </td>
   <tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <span>
           <hr>
           This is not working properly.
       </span>
     </td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103404/problem-in-drawing-a-line-in-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp) And
[Here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894329/code-isnt-drawing-a-horizontal-line-in-my-pdf)

Comment: Thanks Haris. I need a equivalent of <br/> I am not using code behind pdf element creation. I have simple html which I need to show. In particular I want to show only bottom border of a table row.

Comment: What version of Itextsharp are you using?

Comment: @NilThe version is 5.4.1.0.

Comment: See the this link where number of function about itextSharp is given http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/12/06/Using-iTextSharp-with-aspnet-to-add-header-in-pdf-file.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following creates a full width black line a few pixels thick, I'm using `HTMLWorker.Parse`:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <span>
           This is working properly.
       </span>
    </td>
   <tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <span>
       <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>

           This is working properly now too!
       </span>
    </td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. This will create a line of 2px width. But I wonder if there is any other way of doing this. I will mark is answer as accepted if no better answer is provided within 1-2 days.

Comment: @Narendra - I agree that this is not an ideal solution. I started looking through the source code to try and track down how it renders various tags to see if there might be a better option, but I didn't get very far stopped looking.  For the sake of making your xml prettier, you could leave in <hr /> and then do a string replace on <hr /> with the table HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw lines from begining postion (moveto), LineTo and then stroke (commit the line):

```
...
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
....
cb.MoveTo(doc.PageSize.Width / 2, doc.PageSize.Height / 2);     
cb.LineTo(doc.PageSize.Width / 2, doc.PageSize.Height);     
cb.Stroke();
...
```

Comment: Please check the edited question. Actually I am creating the content in xml. Then this xml content is directly used to create pdf. I am not using code-behind pdf elements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you out

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);                //Create a new table with one column
PdfPCell cellLeft = new PdfPCell();                //Create an empty cell
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();               //Declare a stylesheet
style.LoadTagStyle("h1", "border-bottom", "red");          //Create styles for your html tags which you think will be there in PDFText
 List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(PDFText),style);  //This transforms your HTML to a list of PDF compatible objects
for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
{
     cellLeft.AddElement((IElement)objects[k]);    //Add these objects to cell one by one
}
table.AddCell(cellLeft);
```